# Resize a ListView depending on how many items?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, resize

How can I resize the height of a ListView depending on how many items are in that ListView? I'm trying to get the text of an item which is clicked, however whenever the user clicks on a space which has no item, there's an error.
The exact error is:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 
>   Parameter name: index.

I'm using the code:

```
label14.Text = myListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();
```

I figured that removing the space below the items will solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do to fix your error is check to see whether the user actually clicked on an item:

```
if (myListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
    label14.Text = myListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It says I'm missing a assembly reference. Thanks.

Comment: Oops. `Count` is the correct property - the compiler was looking for an extension method with that name, or similar, IIRC. :)

Answer (score 0):

The height of each item is what, around 5-7 pixels depending on the font/font size used. So you can simply do  myListView1.Height = myListView1.Items.Count * itemHeight;

To remove empty list items you can iterate through and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Aha. I've got it working. I used:

```
if (myListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            label14.Text = myListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();
        }
```

That seemed to do the trick. Thanks again for the help!